# How to create an interactive image in SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, interactive

I'm converting a desktop training application to a SharePoint 2007 website. This is a little hard to describe, but one feature of the application is a section of training instructions coupled with a photograph. Imagine a photograph of a kitchen on the left and a scrollable section of text information on how to use the kitchen on the right. The text on the right will be rich text from SP reusable content. The photograph has several dots marked on various places of interest in the kitchen with a little color coded box containing a text description of the point it's next to. When you hover over text instructions in the right section, the corresponding dot for that area of the kitchen needs to be highlighted (a thicker, or wider border on the dot and description box, maybe a lighter background color). So if I hover or click the paragraph about the refrigerator in the right pane, the dot and description over the photo on the left would become highlighted.

My experience with asp.net has been very data driven and the web has become a lot more visually capable since then. Would DHTML, Silverlight, or something else be the best option for this? We cannot use Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined either DHTML or Silverlight would be fine. We ended up going with Silverlight 5 because we are more adept to that technology and even though there may not be a Silverlight 6, MS will continue to support Silverlight 5 long enough for our needs (until 2023 or something like that). I gave the jquery MapHilight plugin a shot, but couldn't find any support on how to use it